# "Element does not define a default property" error when trying to add ToggleButton to a TableColumn in FXML

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, xmltable

When I was taught to make GUIs in school, it seemed like the best way to stick to an MVC approach was to make the markup with... a markup language (FXML), rather than having lengthy, verbose Java code like `table.add(...)` however many times I need it.
Unfortunately, I'm finding it difficult to find FXML troubleshooting resources online.

**My Problem:**
I'm trying to put a toggle button inside of a TableColumn element using FXML. This is what my code looks like, but it doesn't work. It gives the error:

> Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Element does not define a default property.

It's caused by the line below where I add the ToggleButton:

```
<TableColumn>
  <columns>
    <TableColumn >
      <ToggleButton />
    </TableColumn>
   </columns>
 </TableColumn>
```

For the sake of legibility, I've left out the properties of the elements - they aren't causing the error.

I tried adding a `<children>` element to put the ToggleButton in, but apparently it can only be used with a pane.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm trying to put a  ToggleButton in a TableColumn?" Are you just trying to use a toggle button as the graphic for the column? Or do you want each cell in that column to display a toggle button?

Comment: I'd like to have the ToggleButton display inside of the individual cell. It's only three cells I'm doing it with and they're the head column cells (or top, whichever it is called). They're acting as filter toggles, which is why I want to keep toggle functionality to a toggle button.

Comment: Your comment's not very clear to me. The header is something completely distinct from the cells. The cells display the table data. So can you clarify if you are displaying the toggle button in the header, or in (some or all of) the cells?